# Error finding assets when running laravel artisan in host

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 8 and trying to host my project to public localhost using `php artisan serve --host '0.0.0.0' --port 8080` so I can access it from another device, but got the error message:

```
GET <ip>:8080/css/app.css net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)
GET <ip>:8080/js/app.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)
```

I've used laravel `mix` and stored them in `public/css` and `public/js`. Here is my base laravel blade template code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('layouts.navbar')
    @yield('content')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried adding `ASSET_URL=public` in `.env` file, but still not working. Any help would be much appreciated, thank's in advanced!

Comment: You can go to check in your browser and see what is in your link tag. Solve the problem based on that

Comment: Yes, I have checked the link to the CSS file, it redirects me to the CSS file when I clicked it.  But, I'm not sure why the project cannot recognize it. The link is `<ip>:8080/css/app.css`

Comment: can you try run without specific port like this. `php artisan serve`

Comment: Yes, I did, and it worked perfectly. But I need to host it publicly.

Comment: *it worked perfectly without passing the specific IP and port.

Comment: maybe you served another project in that port.  or another way you can replace `asset` with `public_path`